# I have a Site in Silex i want to run other CMS

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, silex

I have a Root Site running properly in Silex i want to run other CMS in domainname.com/news

now the problem is bcos of route it giving me error

No route found for "GET /news/"

how to make this work ? using Mod_rewrite ?

I have upload the CMS in Root/News

(Adding routing rules from comment)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

added bellow

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Now i able to install the script but still its not opening when going frm subdomain news.domainname.com

Comment: you uploaded your CMS in Root/News or Root/news? In case you did in Root/News then access your website with example.com/News instead of /news.

Comment: i tried both /News /news same error. bcos of silex route. i dont know how to switch it off for /news subdirectory

Comment: can you post your rewrite rules? You should do it in apache, when you hit Silex it's already too late to load the other CMS (it's possible but very inefficient)

Comment: hi ya i dont want to hit silex. i want it to run separate. frm subdomain or otherwise. i tried to create subdomain too but its redirecting to silex route not found error. 
news.domainname.com 
this is my running rules 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]

Comment: https://domainname.com/news/public/news/article-title-url 
its now working like this.